# Is it possible to get any OTHER uchiwa fans in Animal Crossing New Horizions?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

I do think the concept of an uchiwa fan is pretty cool after I first saw one in the "Redeem miles" section of the Nook Stop in Resident Services, but I didn't want my uchiwa fan to be this weird green one with big bold letters that say "NOOK INC." on them. I thought that maybe Kicks would have some in store or maybe the Able Sisters carried some once you got their store, but no. I can't find any other uchiwa fan besides the ugly Nook Inc one. Is there any other uchiwa fans in the game? If so, how do I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the listings on [Nookazon](https://nookazon.com/products?search=fan), I'm going to venture that there are no other fans in the game currently.

Emphasis on "currently" -- I wouldn't be surprised to see more added in future holidays (Lunar New Year seems a likely candidate, though that's fairly far away).

Comment: Whats a luner new year?

Comment: @Ari aka Chinese New Year. I know Fire Emblem Heroes has had Lunar New Year-themed events with the characters wielding fans.